# AngularJS ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs

I have just created a very simple app. 
It only contains one function which is used in ng-click. 
Somehow, ng-click is not firing. 
Can anyone take a look for me? 

Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DxwX5sJVaKABeC2JBF8M?p=preview

HTML

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('createController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.submitProject = function(){
    alert('wahaha');
};

}]);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="submitProject()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your plunker is incomplete, it does not have a reference to angular.  It also is not using the correct syntax for creating an angular module, and it is not including a reference to the controller object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ng-controller, so ng-click will know which controller is the function.

```
    <div class="form-group text-right" ng-controller="createController as create">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="create.submitProject()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

I recommend using controllerAs, try reading about this in this [article](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/).

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind your controller by adding an ng-controller attribute like

```
<body ng-controller="createController">
```

to an element that encompasses the html that you would like to bind the scope of your createController to.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the controller to an outer Div will solve your problem.

```
 <div ng-controller='createController' class="form-group text-right">
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the module 'myApp' is not correctly instantiated. It should be:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

This is because you need to pass in an array which is the list of modules myApp depends on. In this case, it is an empty array.

You will also need to add the controller to the view as suggested by previous answers.